# Can Jenkins agent machine be configured for two different servers

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

Hello At work we have two Jenkins controllers but at the moment we have limited agent machines, I was asked to research if it's possible to configure an agent machine for two different controllers?
So, if I would use a machine as an agent I would do these steps:

1-Install Jenkins on the agent machine.

2-On the Jenkins controller, go to "Manage Jenkins" and then click on "Manage Nodes".

3-Click on "New Node" to create a new agent node.

4-Give your agent node a name and select "Permanent Agent" as the type.

5-Click "OK" to create the slave node.

6-On the agent machine, open a terminal and navigate to the Jenkins home directory. This is typically located at `/var/lib/jenkins` on Linux machines.

7-`java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl https://<Jenkins_URL>/computer/<Node_Name>/slave-agent.jnlp -secret <Node_Secret>`
Replace <Jenkins_URL> with the URL of your Jenkins server, <Node_Name> with the name of your slave node, and <Node_Secret> with the secret that was generated for the agent node on the Jenkins controller.

8-The agent should now be connected to the Jenkins controller and ready to run build tasks.

why can't I do the same steps twice for two different controllers, can you explain why it's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you have to configure them differently.

1. Both applications are same so windows/java by default thinks it as reconnection instead of new instance. Not sure but this can work by renaming your jnlp files.
2. Both the application needs to configure to use different IP to avoid connection error.

Comment: can you explain more please what you mean by both applications are the same ?

Comment: both are jenkins.jnlp and you run the  file multiple time it will try to reconnect instead of creating new instance of the application, its an inbuild approach jenkins follows to avoid running multiple instances